# What is the swift equivalent to _cmd?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, selector

I want to get current method name to use in a format message similar to this one

```
[NSExeception raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"You must override %@ in a subclass", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)]
```

Also, I want to use _cmd to set associated object. I appreciate any idea.

Comment: [`__FUNCTION__`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-XID_691)

Comment: How this question is duplicate?

Comment: This is a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24483379/cmd-in-swift-language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Swift equivalent of `_cmd`. There is little reason to use it in Swift.

Consider `_cmd` in Objective-C. When is it useful? Most of the time, the value of `_cmd` would be the same as the name of the method that the code is in, so it is already known at compile time, and there is no need for a runtime value. Here are some possible cases when `_cmd` is useful in Objective-C:

- In a macro. The macro is expanded in the code, so if `_cmd` appears in the macro, then it is inserted into the source where it is used, and so the method name can be used inside the macro. However, such macros do not exist in Swift. Plus macros are compile-time, so a compile-time mechanism like `__FUNCTION__` would work similarly.
- You can define a C function that takes `self` and `_cmd`, and use it (the same function) as the implementation of multiple methods, by adding it using `class_addMethod` and `class_replaceMethod`, and the `_cmd` inside the function will help distinguish between the different method calls. However, `class_addMethod` and `class_replaceMethod` are not available in Swift.
- Method swizzling is also a process that messes with the implementation of a method. Since in swizzling you swap the implementations of two methods, `_cmd` will help reveal the actual method name used in the call, which may not match the method that the code is in in the source code, since implementations are swapped. I guess method swizzling may still be possible in Swift, since `method_exchangeImplementations` is still available in Swift. But in method swizzling, the method you swap in is tailored for the method it is swapping with, so if it is called, there is no ambiguity which method name is being called.
- In the case where you manually get the `IMP` (implementing function) of a method, and manually call it with a different selector. In this case, the inside of the function can see the different selector in `_cmd`. However, you don't have to worry about this in Swift because the methods that get the `IMP` are unavailable.

Comment: Swizzling should be a last emergency solution for framework bugs. Said that, here's a post about the Swift run-time by **NSHipster** [swizzling in Swift](http://nshipster.com/swift-objc-runtime/)

Comment: I beg to differ.  Sort Descriptors.  I like to use a method's accessor name, so that if the attribute's name changes, the compiler complains.

Comment: Aside swizzling, one reason would be to override an optional protocol selector more cleanly.  If super.responds(to:_cmd) would be a clean improvement.

Answer (score 41):

```
NSStringFromSelector(_cmd); // Objective-C

print(#function) // Swift 4, 5
```

Comment: "__FUNCTION__" will be deprecated and will be removed from Swift 3, therefore, use instead: #function

Comment: To be exact debug identifiers like `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, `__COLUMN__` and `__FUNCTION__` have been replaced by `#file`, `#line`, `#column` and `#function` in **Swift 2.2**.

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0028-modernizing-debug-identifiers.md

Comment: This is not same. `_cmd` is a selector type, and `#function` is not `#selector` type.