# _cmd in Swift language

Tags: ios, swift, selector

My previous question was marked duplicate. I tried to edit my question, but I can't remove duplicate tag, so I have to create a new one
[What is the swift equivalent to _cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24482670/what-is-the-swift-equivalent-to-cmd)

I want to get current method name to use in a format message similar to this one

```
[NSExeception raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"You must override %@ in a subclass", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)]
```

Also, I want to use _cmd as key to set associated object. Does anyone know the equivalent of _cmd in Swift I really appreciate.

Comment: Your question was marked as a duplicate because it already has an answer: see the link on your old question. If you feel that it is not a duplicate, visit [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/), but please read the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) first.

Comment: did you tried `__FUNCTION__`? if it is not what you want, make it clear in original question. we will reopen it if need to.

Comment: I know how to use __FUNCTION__, but I want something like _cmd, cause it can be used in other case

Comment: Is this really no _cmd in Swift?

Comment: `println(__FUNCTION__)`

Comment: `#function` as of Swift 3.0

Answer (score 24):

There's no `_cmd`, but you can use `__FUNCTION__` to get the name of the current function, which can be used in place of selectors most of the time.

```
func myUnimplementedMethod() {
    println("You must override \(__FUNCTION__) in a subclass")
}
myUnimplementedMethod()
// prints "You must override myUnimplementedMethod() in a subclass"
```

Comment: Note that `__FUNCTION__` was replaced with `#function`in Swift 2.2.